# Error en sintaxis iteración Json Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tengo el siguiente código y me aparece un error.

La idea es iterar lo que esta dentro del each y estas iteraciones a su vez quedarán dentro de json.datos para ocupar esos datos en otra función.

El problema es que me aparece un error de las llaves o el punto y coma, creo que debe ser la sintaxis.

```
json.datos=[
    $.each(data.cosas, function(i, valores){
        [valores.id, valores.nombre],
        ];
});
```

ejemplo

```
json.datos=[
    $.each(data.fruteria, function(i, valores){
         [0, banana],
         [1, manzana],
         [2, frambuesa],
         ];
    });
```

Comment: estás realizando un `$.each` dentro de un `array`, esto no se puede...

Comment: ¿No sería tan simple como asignar `data.fruteria` a `json.datos`?

Comment: Tu código es erróneo, siempre cuando abras con uno de estos bloques `[({`, debes cerrar primero con el mismo tipo de bloque `})]`. Por lo tanto, `[({})]` es correcto, pero `[(]{)}` es incorrecto. Por otro lado estás insertando un `each` dentro de un `Array` como bien comenta @Jorius.

Answer (score 1):

Pues no puedes dejar adentro el each.

Sin embargo puedes probar con esto:

```
var arr = []; //Defines un array
$.each(data.fruteria, function(i, valores){ //Iteras los resultados
   arr[i] = valores.nombre; //Le colocas un valor a cada dimensión del array
};

var datos = JSON.stringify(arr); //Le pasas el array definido para que este lo pase a json
```

De esta manera pasas el array a un json.

Espero que te haya ayudado y éxito en tu proyecto.

**NOTA:**

Con referente a tu comentario, puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
var arr = new Array();
var listaArr = new Array();
$.each(data.fruteria, function(i, valores){ 
   arr.length=0;
   arr.push(i);
   arr.push(valores.nombre); 
   listaArr.push(arr);
};

var datos = JSON.stringify(listaArr);
```

Comment: Creo que se te han colado unos `[]` en la línea de `arr[i] = [valores.nombre];`. No debería ser en todo caso `arr[i] = valores.nombre;`?

Comment: No me había dado cuenta @frikinside, allí lo edite, gracias :D Y coméntanos como solucionaste finalmente Santy, para que otros usuarios les puedas ser de utilidad :D

Comment: Secundo lo que dice José Miguel, si has encontrado una respuesta a tu pregunta sería de mucha utilidad a otros usuarios que publicaras una respuesta a tu misma pregunta con la solución. Cuéntanos si te encuentras algún problema @SantySC !

Comment: no me sirvio lo que pensé que me podría ayudar :/ y no es adjuntar valor  por valor sino que un push de array dentro de un array. 

por ejemplo:

json.datos=[ [valores.id, valores.nombre],
 [valores.id, valores.nombre],
 [valores.id, valores.nombre],
];

Answer (score 0):

Como te puse en los comentarios, tu código es erróneo. No es correcto en primer lugar porque no cierras los bloques de código de la manera correcta (he situado cada cierre de bloque exactamente debajo de donde abre para que notes el error):

```
datos = [
    $.each(data.cosas, function (i, valores) {
        [valores.id, valores.nombre],
];
    });
```

Por otro lado, no puedes situar bloques de código dentro de un `Array`, entre el corchete de apertura del `Array` y el corchete de cierre, solo deben estar los valores de este tipo de objeto separados por coma.

Lo que deseas hacer lo puedes lograr fácilmente con el método [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) de la clase [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array). Suponiendo que tus datos consisten en un `Array` de `Strings` puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
var datos = ["banana", "manzana", "frambuesa"];

var array = datos.map(function (str, index) {

  return [index, str];

});

console.log(array);
```